# Prove a sequence of integrals converges to 0

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a set of finite Lebesgue measure in ${\bf R}$ and $\{a_n\}_{n \in {\bf N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers.

Show that

$\int_E \cos(nx + a_n) dx $ goes to 0 as $n \to \infty$.

I tried expanding it to $\int_E \cos(nx) \cos(a_n) - \sin(nx)\sin(a_n) dx$ but that doesn't seem to help.  We have $e^{inx} : n \in {\bf N}$ is dense for any irrational x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E \cos(nx) \, dx = 0$. You can do this directly or via the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. Since $\{\cos (a_n)\}$ is a bounded sequence it follows that
$$ \int_E \cos(nx) \cos (a_n) \, dx  = \cos(a_n) \int_E \cos(nx) \, dx \to 0.
$$

The same argument works to show
$$ \int_E \sin(nx) \sin (a_n) \, dx \to 0.$$